# Add custom input form in MediaWiki homepage

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor

Where can I put custom input form code in media wiki homepage?

This is so I can modify it into fewer steps for a user to create a new page. The input form will be for entering the title of the new page.

Currently, when adding a page, the user has to search for a page, and if it doesn't exist, it redirects to another page with a link to add the new page. After that it will load the built-in Wiki editor(will also modify this to default to the Visual Editor extension I integrated instead of Wiki editor).

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The file in which i can add/modify a custom input form in the media wiki homepage would be the /rootWikiDir/skins/Vector.php

Comment: Note that that file will be overwritten no the next upgrade. It's safer to create (and easier to maintain) your own extension, if you want to modify page output.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. This is only a short-term solution for now since the deadline was set soon. Thanks for the input leo.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of extensions that can do what you want:

- [InputBox](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aInputBox), is bundled with recent versions of MediaWiki. It is used with Wikimedia wikis, and thus probably very stable.
- [CreateBox](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCreateBox), specifically for letting users create pages
- [Create Page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCreate_Page), more general aproach
- [Semantic Forms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSemantic_Forms) The most fulfledged, but also the most complex, and requires the Semantic MediaWiki extension

You might also want to combine this with some biolerplate extension, e.g. [Preloader](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPreloader)

As you are posting on SO, I assume that developing your own extension would also be an option. In that case, have a look at the parser functions manual: [https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser_functions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParser_functions)

Comment: Actually, im not looking for an extension. I just want to add to the current code so I could place an input form. See, I installed a Visual Editor extension. When I add a new page, it still redirects to the built-in editor only with a create button/tab at the upper right that can be clicked to load the newly added Visual Editor. I would want to load the Visual Editor by default, not the built-in editor.

Comment: This is the URL structure for the built-in editor: `http://wiki.loc.com/index.php?title=TitleOfNewPage&action=edit&redlink=1` and this would be for the Visual Editor: `http://wiki.loc.com/index.php?title=TitleOfNewPage&veaction=edit`. I would use the input form to just redirect to the Visual Editor URL structure and concatenate the title retrieved from the input form for which i dont know where to place.

Comment: Why not just make VE the default editor for new users? '$wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-enable'] = 1;'.  For existing users there is a maintainance script to change everyone's preference. Try googling it

Comment: I've already added that in the LocalSettings.php but the first editor shown when creating/editing a page is still the built-in editor. Only that theres now a button that loads the visual editor.